# IP Telephony - Connect 2 Users Anonymously?

Tags: skype, telephony

**I need to connect two users via IP telephony in an anonymous fashion.**

Ideally they would both click some button (say on a web site or some piece of client software) and enter into some queue that I maintain server side.

When there's enough users in the queue I would pair them up and connect them in an anonymous fashion. At this point they would carry on a normal conversation and when one ended the conversation they would have no way of contacting each other again.

**Update: It's fine if the users choose to share contact details, I'd just like to provide an anonymous setting for them to meet.** If for some reason they share phone numbers (or sniff IP addresses) that's fine.

I'm a pretty big newb when it comes to telephony in general, **can I do this with a Skype plug in or some other popular piece of desktop software? Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/)

Your callers would log in with an Asterisk account on the Asterisk box (using a SIP or IAX account), perform a local call (say to "555") and then you use scripting on the Asterisk side to connect calls.

As long as the Asterisk box is doing transcoding, there is no direct contact in between peers.

As for caller id, that's a local extension so irrelevant to identifying the other peer. Plus, you can block the caller id from Asterisk too.